# How to align a number to the right in Jupyter notebook math mode

Tags: formatting, latex, jupyter-notebook

Apologies if this is a stupid question, but I searched a lot and couldn't find out how to do this. In math mode if I'm trying to write the equations

```
$$x=2  x=3$$
```

How do I align the x=3 to the right side of the page? I tried \hfill but it didn't seem to do anything. Thanks!

Comment: I know nothing about Jupyter, but try `$$\makebox[\textwidth]{$x = 2$\hfill$x = 3$}$$`.

Answer (score 3):

Placing right-align text with `markdown` code is not possible. However, if you add a `\tag{xx}`, i.e. for equation number, you get the tag's content on the right side. And the the equation in the center. For example:-

```
$$x=2  x=3 \tag{2.a}$$
```

You get something like:        x=2 x=3                                                      (2.a)

To get what you want, you need to use HTML code instead. For example, write this code:

```
<div style='text-align: right'><em>x=2 x=3</em></div>
```

in a markdown cell and run it, you should get the result you want.